# Passing feature names to an estimator through the ColumnTransformer in sklearn

Tags: python, class, scikit-learn, pipeline

I am making a custom Linear Regression class, that splits the dataset by the unique values of certain column and makes prediction for all groups separately. So, one of the arguments in **init** function is the feature, which values must be the key to split a dataset. It works well with pandas.Dataframe and with data and columns given independently. BUT! When i make an estimator a last stage of a pipeline, my construction fails, because ColumnTransformer looses the names on its way and feeds an estimator a pure np.array.

how to assign the transformed data its new names and use it in the last stage of pipeline?
(i don't transform my key-feature somehow and ready that its name will become like remainder__feature)

**UPD. I found a bad solution. I made another "Transformer", that is returning the dataframe itself, but being applied to only one column in a pipeline, it simply puts the column on a first place in the new transformed dataset. And my custom class takes it from there. It works anyway, but if anyone has a better solution, please ping me!**

Here are the class and the pipeline

```
class BinClipLinearRegression():
    def __init__(self, feature, columns=None, clip=False):

        self.columns=columns
        if self.columns:
            self.feature = [i for i in columns if feature in i][0]
        else:
            self.feature = feature
        self.clip = clip

    def fit(self, x, y, ymin=y.min(), ymax=y.max()):
        if self.columns:
            x = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=self.columns)
            try: # это если передан Series с индексами
                y = y.reset_index(drop=True)
            except:
                pass

        self.ymin = ymin
        self.ymax = ymax
        models = {}
        self.uniques = x[self.feature].unique()
        for f in self.uniques:
            xx = x[x[self.feature]==f]
            yy = y[xx.index]
            models[f] = LinearRegression().fit(xx, yy)
        self.models = models
        # return xx
        return self

    def predict(self, x):
        if self.columns:
            x = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=self.columns)
        x = x.reset_index(drop=True)

        y_pred = np.full([x.shape[0], 1], np.nan)
        for f in self.uniques:
            y_pred[x[x[self.feature]==f].index, :] = self.models[f].predict(x[x[self.feature]==f]).reshape(-1, 1)

        y_pred[np.where(np.isnan(y_pred))] = np.nanmedian(y_pred)

        if self.clip:
            return np.clip(y_pred, self.ymin, self.ymax)
        return y_pred
```

And here is the pipeline

```
num_ct_robust = Pipeline(steps=[('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='median')),
                                ('scaler', RobustScaler(quantile_range=(15, 85)))])

cat_ct = Pipeline(steps=[('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent')),
                         ('ohe', OneHotEncoder(drop='first', handle_unknown='infrequent_if_exist'))])

transformer = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('nums_robust', num_ct_robust, ('registration_year', 'power',)),
                                              ('cats', cat_ct, selector(dtype_include='object'))],
                                remainder='passthrough')

lr_pipe = Pipeline([('transformer', transformer),
                    ('estimator', BinClipLinearRegression(feature='vintage'))])
```

I updated my class to be able to get np.array and columns names to try this

```
lr_pipe = Pipeline([('transformer', transformer),
                    ('estimator', BinClipLinearRegression(feature='vintage',  
   **columns=transformer.get_feature_names_out()**))])
```

But it expectedly says:

```
NotFittedError: This ColumnTransformer instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this estimator.
```